# Plugin for jquery for date clears textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

[I use this jquery plugin for date](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

I have input in the updatePanel

```
 <input id="DateMask" type="text" />
```

and js code:

```
 function SetD() {
     alert(1);
     $("#DateMask").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "_" });
 }


  $(document).ready(function () {
     SetD();
  });
```

It is supposed to mask my date it does so but when i press enter my inut clears text
if i just click on another input text remains.
so what is the problem?

upd: jquery version:`<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Upd2: i've changed input to textbox and it worked what a hell??

Comment: make a fiddle or tell what version of jQuery library and plugin you are using

Answer (score 1):

How many of your inputs also have the **ID** of `DateMask`? Change them to **classes** and your problems will vanish.

```
<input class="DateMask" type="text" />
function SetD() {
    alert(1);
    $(".DateMask").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "_" });
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
     SetD();
 });
```

Comment: thanks))))))))))))))  i have already actuaally switched to jquery datepicker but thanks anyway))

Comment: upd: sorry the problem still remains now with the jquery datepicker(

Comment: I don't know how well datepicker is going to get along with the datemask routines. For datepicker, you should be using the `dateFormat` property.